# Add yes/no confirmation

Tags: python-3.x, xcode, input, printing

im new in python and its my first new code and i have problem with my input confirmation
how can say to python if some one use y continue code and run it?

```
import datetime
import random
import time

print('Enter your name:')
x = input()
print('Hello, ' + x) 
throw_start = input("Want to start triger C4!?(y/n)\n")
if throw_start == 'y':
        ****??????** = True**
    else:
        quit()
add =  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59]
for i in range(3):
    right_this_minute = datetime.today() .minute
    today = datetime.today()
    today_persian = jdatetime.datetime.now()
    print("Time is:",today)
    print("Persian Time is:",today_persian)
    if right_this_minute in add:
        print ("Number is ODD")
    else:
        print("Number is not ODD")
    w8_time = random.randint(1,10)
    for i in range(w8_time):
        print(str(w8_time - i) + " Second to Blowup")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("BOOOOOOOOM,Lets go next ")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `if throw_start != 'y': 
     exit()`
Should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that simplest solution for you would be to just put pass in that if condition.

```
if throw_start == 'y':
    pass
else:
    quit()
```

So that if answer is 'y' just continue and if answer is anything else quit()

or you can also negate your condition, so quit if answer is not 'y'

```
if throw_start != 'y':
        quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have problem with indentation + you also placed the content of the if statement in the wrong place
the following solution should solve your current problem

```
import datetime
```

import random
import time

```
x = input('Enter your name:')
   print('Hello, ' + x) 
   throw_start = input("Want to start triger C4!?(y/n)\n")
   if throw_start == 'y':
       add =  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59]
       for i in range(3):
           right_this_minute = datetime.today() .minute
           today = datetime.today()
           today_persian = datetime.datetime.now()
           print("Time is:",today)
           print("Persian Time is:",today_persian)
           if right_this_minute in add:
               print ("Number is ODD")
           else:
               print("Number is not ODD")
           w8_time = random.randint(1,10)
           for i in range(w8_time):
               print(str(w8_time - i) + " Second to Blowup")
               time.sleep(1)
           print("BOOOOOOOOM,Lets go next ")
           time.sleep(5)
   else:
       quit()
```

Notice that you have another problem in this line `right_this_minute = datetime.today() .minute` I am not sure what you are trying to do but you better learn more about python's datetime library

Answer (score 0):

the essention part is this:

```py
if throw_start == 'y':
    pass
else:
    exit()
```

but there were so many errors in the code (imports / typos), that it needed to be re-written to work. also note, that the code does not appear to stop (infnite loop).

Anyway, here is the full code

```py
import datetime
import random
import time


print('Enter your name:')
x = input()
print('Hello, ' + x) 
throw_start = input("Want to start triger C4!?(y/n)\n")
if throw_start == 'y':
    pass
else:
    exit()
add =  [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59]
for i in range(3):
    right_this_minute = datetime.datetime.today() .minute
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    today_persian = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Time is:",today)
    print("Persian Time is:",today_persian)
    if right_this_minute in add:
        print ("Number is ODD")
    else:
        print("Number is not ODD")
    w8_time = random.randint(1,10)
    for i in range(w8_time):
        print(str(w8_time - i) + " Second to Blowup")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("BOOOOOOOOM,Lets go next ")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: thank you for your help
its just game loop for defuse c4 before timer show 0
for next level i need put hiden key in game that player push bottom like space c4 triger make stop and show winning message for safe people life :))
im very new in python like 1 week learning and your help is awesome

Comment: you are welcome.  generally you should follow this guide for question asking:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  which makes it easier for others to help you progress.